# Storing Time Ranges in mySQL database and comparing with Current time

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, codeigniter, time

I have a database table storing opening hours of a shop as a time range as a VARCHAR like '9am-5pm' and '9am-3pm, 5pm-11pm'. I want to compare these opening hours with the current time, so if the current time is 2pm, I will use PHP to echo a text stating that the shop is now open, and if the current time is 11.30pm, the shop will be shown as closed.

1. How do I compare the current time with the opening hours time range in the tables
2. Is my method of storing time range suitable?

I'm using Codeigniter, so if theres useful functions do let me know too!

Comment: You'd be a lot better off storing this in MySQL in a way where you could use the MySQL Date/Time Functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use 2 columns (one for open time, one for close time) both using the `TIME` datatype: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time.html

By doing that, you can then use `BETWEEN` and `NOW()`: `SELECT * FROM shop WHERE CAST(NOW() AS TIME) BETWEEN open_time AND close_time;`

Edit to include table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE shop_hours (
  shop_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  day_of_week INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- 0-6
  open_time TIME NOT NULL,
  close_time TIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(shop_id, day_of_week, open_time, close_time)
);
```

Comment: How should I handle times with a break inbetween like '9am-1pm, 3pm-9pm'?

Comment: Some shops have just one time range, some have two, so I need a method that is general and works for both single and multiple time ranges

Comment: Multiple rows per shop would support this.  Your PK would have to include `shop_id, open_time, close_time`

Comment: I think having an additional row may increase the query time as there are long formulas to compute for each row and having duplicate rows for additional time ranges may be computationally intensive.

Comment: If I decide to have a max of 2 time ranges, will 4 columns work for open_time_1, close_time_1, open_time_2, close_time_2?

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to choose a limit that isn't 0, 1, or infinity, but you could certainly make the above work.

Comment: opening times often depends on day, maybe better idea to add an day (0-6) column. Pk can't be on (shop_id, open_time, close_time) because as asked above, shops can have two time ranges for a day (8am-11am + 1pm-7pm). Also think about range days : Monday to Friday : 8am-11am + 1pm 7M, Saturday to Sunday : 10am to 6pm .. @nyxnyx : have you find your solution ?

Comment: @Julien: A day column would be a good idea as well. I'm not sure why you think the PK can't be (shop_id, open_time, close_time). Using your example, there are two tuples (assume shop_id = 1): (1, 08:00:00, 11:00:00), (1, 13:00:00, 19:00:00). Unless you meant with the addition of day_of_week, it should also be part of the PK, since the same shop could have the same hours on different days of the week (M-F), which is why I added it to the PK.

Comment: but this would complicate the issue if multiple timezones are involved. Or if server has a different timezone than where the sops are

Comment: `TIME` doesn't include a timezone (see the mysql doc I linked). In a model like this, you'd likely want to store the timezone of the shop as an attribute of the shop, and use that to localize the information you show to end users. If you instead tried to use a datatype that supports a timezone, you'd have to include a meaningless date as part of it, and you'd still have challenges with DST if the region used it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend two separate columns instead, one for opening time and one for closing time.

Answer (score 1):

Use two columns in the 24h format. It's saner for computers to process, and you will be able to use standard numerical comparisons. You can always convert to AM/PM when printing.